# How to have a static background

Tags: css, background

Does anyone know how to keep a constant background so that when you scroll down a page it seems like everything is moving but the background image...basically a static background.

Comment: I am not sure but try to use **background-position:fixed;**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a CSS attribute called `background-attachment: fixed;`
Use it with the `background-image` attribute within the same element.

Comment: I added it to my site, but it doesn't work on the mobile version

Comment: What's your mobile device and what browser do you use on it? You may re-read my answer in case you followed the first version of it which was wrong.

Comment: It is an Iphone and I am using safari

Comment: Known issue with older iOS versions AFAIK. You may want to search for an alternative regarding this case.